# Test View in Django that requires Login session Selenium

Tags: django, selenium

I would like to test a View in Django using Sellenium that has a decorator, that requires being logged in:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
```

This is how mu code looks like:

```
class TestAddOrder(LiveServerTestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
    super(TestAddOrder, self).setUp()


  def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.quit()
    super(TestAddOrder, self).tearDown()

  def test_add_order(self):
    selenium = self.selenium
    selenium.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/create/')

    date = selenium.find_element_by_name('date').send_keys('01/31/2019')
    hours = selenium.find_element_by_id('id_hour').send_keys('18')

    submit = selenium.find_element_by_name('submit').send_keys(Keys.RETURN).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

And the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="date"]
```

How can I keep the session of logged in user when trying to automise my test with Sellenium?

Answer (score 1):

In your `setUp()` method you should create a user, log in the user and set the session cookie so that it's sent with every subsequent request:

```py
def setUp(self):
    self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
    super().setup()
    user = User.objects.create_user(...)
    self.client.force_login(user)  # TestCase client login method
    session_key = self.client.cookies[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME].value
    self.selenium.get('http://127.0.0.1/')  # load any page
    self.selenium.add_cookie({'name': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, 'value': session_key, 'path': '/'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I added your code I got 'Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.' So I changed http://127.0.0.1 -> http://127.0.0.1:8000. And still there is a problem: "Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/create/accounts/user_login?next=/orders/create/".

Comment: I don’t know the details of your site. My line `get('http...')` is just an example, any page of your site works even one that returns 404. Shouldn’t stop the test from running. Where does the test actually fail?

Comment: It fails when it is trying to get `selenium.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/create/')` since it is getting `127.0.0.1:8000/orders/create/accounts/user_login?next=/orders/create` instead.

Comment: The problem is apparently still the same - not being logged in.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in your test code and stepping through the code to see what's going on. Right now it's impossible for me to tell why it's not working. Also, the URL you get to redirect a user to login (`/orders/create/accounts/user_login`) is completely wrong, so that's a mistake in your code, not in your test.